# UI designer overwrite property of my own inherit control

Tags: c#, winforms

I created my own control by inheriting from *System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel*. I need to fix the number of row and col as 1.

```
public class KTextPanel : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public KTextPanel()
    {
        ColumnCount = 1;
        RowCount = 1;
    }
}
```

So I implemented it in the constructor of the new control. Problem is that when I generate a new instance of my new control on UI designer, UI designer overwrite the number of row and col as 2 in [*blah.designer.cs*] automatically.

```
// 
// kTextPanel8
// 
this.kTextPanel8.AANAME = "Force Pickup";
this.kTextPanel8.AANODENAME = "picker";
this.kTextPanel8.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.kTextPanel8.ColumnCount = 2;
this.kTextPanel8.RowCount = 2;
```

it looks 2 is the default value of the TableLayoutPanel. How can I prevent this automatic routine done by UI designer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just override the designer, but setting the values you want in the form constructor after the call to InitializeComponent().  Or go into the designer and use the property window to set the properties of your control there, the should change what gets generated by the designer.

Comment: Now I just moved my settings from _Constructor_ into _HandleCreatedEvent_ so that it is applied my intentional property values as considering function callback sequential timing. By the way, isn't there a way to stop UI Designer for writing default properties in _InitializeComponent()_ for only the specific control?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) Attribute

something like this should work:

```
public class KTextPanel : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public KTextPanel()
    {
        ColumnCount = 1;
        RowCount = 1;
    }

    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public new int ColumnCount
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ColumnCount;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ColumnCount = value;
        }
    }

    //... same for RowCount
}
```